# Comparison between to have the good luck "of getting" and "to get" (a thing)?

Tags: phrase-usage

I am not a native speaker of English and it's a little confusing for me to differentiate between phrases of the type:

> I had the *good fortune / hap* of getting ...

versus

> I had the *good fortune / hap* to get ...

and their equivalent - e.g. "I was fortunate ...", "I had the stroke of luck ...".

I am used to perceive the gerund form as indicating a prolonged experience, and the to+inf form - general events or events which occur only once; however, I'm not sure whether this is the case here. For example, I've heard before people saying:

> Yesterday I had the fortune of meeting SB.

which is clearly an once-occurring event, or:

> I was lucky to sit next to SB (during my flight to London).

which is a prolonged event.

So I'd like to ask what's the rule in the situations above, if there is one?

PS The interpretation that I gave above is based on analogy with the phrase:

> I had the pleasure to do something (once) / of doing something (for a period of time).

Comment: Hi, and welcome. This is an interesting question; I'm not sure there is a hard and fast rule regarding the use of the gerund and time. As an English speaker, the gerund form sounds appropriate and more natural. "I had the pleasure to" sounds off, but "the pleasure *of* + gerund" sounds fine. Even if an event was short-lived, the lasting effect may be appropriate to consider. Not saying this question is in the wrong place, but you might enjoy  [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour). Exploration of English from a non-native speaker's viewpoint is a main focus.

Comment: What does "**hap**" mean in your first two phrases?

Comment: It means a "lucky occurrence" - [comes from Norse](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hap).